# solr fieldcollapsing and maximum group.limit

Tags: solr, lucene, grouping, fieldcollapsing

I'm using Solr 3.4 and [FieldCollapsing](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FieldCollapsing). I would like to group all messages using FieldCollapsing.

Per default, every group contains only 1 message.

I can modify the numbers of documents per group by changing the Parameter `group.limit`.
That's a bit inconveniently for grouping all available messages to specific groups.

Is there a way to set `group.limit` to infinite?

The current workaround is to set `group.limit` to an very high value, which isn't an satisfying solution.

Comment: Altough Solr is very good at finding the top documents that match a query, it is bad at retrieving lots of documents. What is your use case ? Does your data reside somewhere else (text files? a database?) where this partition could be performed more efficiently?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set `group.limit` to `-1`. Then you will get infinite documents per group.

Comment: Hi ReinierDG. That's it! Thank you! By playing around with this options I found an important notice: using `group.limit=-1` seams to "disable" caching behavior. (or empty the cache or4 whatever) With `group.limit=200` followed by  `group.limit=20` (and so on) caching works fine. Using `-1` I need all the time hundreds of milliseconds to get the result. So finally for me it's faster to use `group.limit=1000000` than `group.limit=-1`

Comment: @TheBndr Your comment should be much more visible. Came to the same conclusion today, took me hours to figure out why the queries were factor 100 slower with group.limit=-1.